using react-native-image-crop-picker multiple true, I want crop all images those I selected
I am using react-native-image-crop-picker
and I have to choose multiple images so I did multiple true,
Now I want crop all images those I selected. because if i am enabling the multiple true it is not cropping.
Cropping working for single image selection.
I want to crop all images those I selected in react native

To achieve this, you can use the react-native-image-crop-picker library to select multiple images and then loop through the selected images to crop each one individually
try {
  const selectedImages = await ImagePicker.openPicker({
    multiple: true,
    mediaType: 'photo',
  });
  // Loop through selected images and crop each one
  selectedImages.forEach(async (image) => {
    try {
      const croppedImage = await ImagePicker.openCropper({
        path: image.path,
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
      });
      console.log('Cropped image:', croppedImage);
      // Do something with the cropped image, like uploading it to a server
    } catch (cropError) {
      console.error('Error cropping image:', cropError);
    }
  });
} catch (pickerError) {
  console.error('Error selecting images:', pickerError);
}

